# Magic Quotes GPC joomla

Tags: php, joomla, magic-quotes-gpc

I cannot install Joomla because I cannot turn Magic Quotes GPC On.I tried to write in .htaccess Magic Quotes GPC On but it doesn't work.And what can I do I have no time.Thank you!
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpe3i.png)

Comment: It needs them on of off? (I thought they needed to be Off. And that screenshot seems to indicate that.) Anyway, if your hosting company has you locked down so that you can't turn them off, then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: No i want to turn on.

Comment: According to your screenshot they ARE on: Magic Quotes GPC Off = No means they are NOT Off, they are On. Joomla wants them Off. Either way, if your hosting locks you down from changing the value of Magic_Quotes_GPC, you can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla does not need `magic_quotes` enabled.

In fact, what the installer is trying to tell you is that they are currently `On` in your web space, but they should be turned `Off` for Joomla to be able to install.